# Why no test is run when execute mvn test -P{profile Id}

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

I have defined my profiles in pom.xml as below:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Test123</id>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- put your configurations here -->
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>src/target/testdemo.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And we I ran a command **mvn test -PTest123**, there is no Tests being run as shown as below:
[cmd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KhDq.png)

However, we I ran with command **mvn test**, it has ran the test as shown as below:
[cmd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay7cM.png)

Comment: You are specifying a suite XML file. So it will run other tests than the default invocation of this plugin. Specifying an XML file in the _target_ directory seems not to be correct. There might be none!

Answer (score -1):

After reviewing the output files I noticed that different versions of the maven-compiler-plugin and maven-surefire-plugin are running per profile. Is this project dependent on a parent pom.xml? Otherwise changing the versions on the plugins to:

```
        <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- put your configurations here -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/target/testdemo.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

should fix the problem in case the versioning is not important.

Comment: I have tried **mvn test -P Test123**, the result still the same. No test is run.